# how to add picked date in a table as a column in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, alter-table

I am trying to add picked date as a column using the following query.  But it shows an error:

> "Error in column alter :ALTER TABLE cse145takeattendance ADD '2017-11-17' date;"

how to overcome this?.

```
$date=$_POST['today'];
$alter="ALTER TABLE cse145takeattendance ADD '$date' date;";
mysqli_query($s,$alter) or die ("Error in column alter :$alter");
```

Comment: ....you want to add column on your DB based on user's input?

Comment: Use mysql tag so people can find your question easier

Comment: try like this `"ALTER TABLE cse145takeattendance ADD ".$date" date;"`

Comment: And I think you want to add date in your table , why you are creating columns for it? I think you should create a column and add your dates to a row

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" date;"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\updatetoday.php on line 9                    @SanchitPatiyal

Comment: @udayasankar had you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406113/how-to-add-picked-date-in-a-table-as-a-column-in-mysql/47406202#47406202

Answer (score 0):

**You need back-ticks around attribute**

Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Which means you must quote it with back ticks like `2017-11-17`:

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @S N Tiwari.   I'm tried but it not affects that table .

Comment: sorry,following query failure in alter ,'"ALTER TABLE cse145takeattendance ADD '.$date' date;" ' @S N Tiwari

Answer (score 0):

Pure number couldn't be a field of table!